# Convert key code to character

Tags: javascript

Why are some keycodes converted to other characters?

http://jsfiddle.net/h9268/

I think 219 should be the [ character.

```
onKeyPress I get 91
onKeyDown I get 219
```

firefox, test page: http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Update: the confusion was generated by the keycode of onKeyPress and onKeyDown event.
onKeyPress the character code is returned ( 91 ) and onKeyDown the key code is returned ( 219 ).

This table shows both ascii code and key code ( by browser ). http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Vision has right, must be `91` not 219

Comment: here is a test page http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Comment: onKeyPress you get the character code, while onKeyDown you get the keyboard key code.

Answer (score 2):

That's for Unicode. It's taking the Unicode values and converting it to Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

It converts to Unicode, here is [Here](http://www.goascii.com/) is table of conversion, use 91 instead

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools says:

```
Definition and Usage

The fromCharCode() method converts Unicode values into characters.

Note: This is a static method of the String object, and the syntax is always String.fromCharCode().
```

Instead of `219` must be `91` for `[` character

`219` means for keyCode not charCode